# PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)) I'm getting this error #Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, exception, mobile

I have integrated firebase firestore with my flutter app recently. Even after following the steps properly, I'm getting this error 'PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null))'. I have tried doing 'flutter clean' and then 'flutter pub get' many times. restarted the editor...but not use...[image]

BTW, I've also tried to configure 'flutterfire configure' using CLI...that returns 0 firebase projects

This is my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: emag
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.6 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  # An SVG rendering and widget library for Flutter, which allows painting and displaying Scalable Vector Graphics 1.1 files.
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.0+1

  # A Flutter Carousel widget.
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1

  # The best swiper for flutter , with multiple layouts, infinite loop. Compatible with Android & iOS.
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6

  # The best swiper(carousel) for flutter, with multiple layouts, infinite loop. Compatible with Android & iOS.
  flutter_swiper_plus: ^2.0.4
  cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.5
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.10
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.17

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/leaderboard.svg
    - assets/images/landscape.jpg
    - assets/images/falls.jpg
    # - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Could anyone spot the reason for this exception?

I have changed some versions of packages that I suspected to be the reason, but no use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow these steps:

Step 1

```
flutter pub outdated
```

Step 2

```
flutter pub upgrade outdated_package
```

Step 3

```
flutter clean
```

Step 4

```
flutter pub get
```

Step 5

```
flutter run
```